# how to permanently hide the keyboard on date picker edit text

Tags: java, android, android-studio, calendar, keyboard

I want to disable the `Keyboard` permanently from a `DatePicker` `EditText` so that I manually have to choose a date from a `DatePicker` dialog...

Here is my java code:

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.*;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EdgeEffect;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
    Spinner spinner;
    EditText Datetxt;
    int Date_x,Month_x,Year_x;
     static final int DIALOG_ID=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Gender,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        showDialogonClick();
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "you select", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }

    public void showDialogonClick()
    {
        Datetxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Datetxt);
        Datetxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DIALOG_ID);
            }

        }

        );
}
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
        if(id==DIALOG_ID)
            return new DatePickerDialog(this,dpickerListener,Date_x,Month_x,Year_x);
        else return null;
    }
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpickerListener= new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int Day, int Month, int Year) {
            Date_x=Day;
            Month_x=Month;
            Year_x=Year;
            //Datetxt.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
            String Date1=Date_x+"."+Month_x+"."+Year_x;
            Datetxt.setText(Date1);

        }
    };

}
```

When I click on `EditText` **both the calendar and keyboard are opened simultaneously.**

Comment: If you don't want it editable, why not just make it a `TextView`?

Answer (score 8):

You can also add these attributes to your EditText in xml file

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:inputType="date"
```

Comment: thanks Marat it also working for me........

Comment: @BHAGAT Happy for you) Then please accept and upvote my answer. I would appreciate that

Comment: @Marat Works for me thanks for your Help

Answer (score 3):

Use this way it solve your Problem.

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Comment: it helps for me....thanks #ironman

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
 myTimePicker.setDescendantFocusability(TimePicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```

to disable focus on the text views of the internal NumberPickers

**Another Way** . Add this in your XML:

`android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

Answer (score 1):

```
android:focusable="false"
android:hint="@string/history_by_date_example"
android:inputType="none"
```

Setting `inputType` to none in your xml file will not open keyboard and you can open date picker dialog on click of your `edittext`